Material Offset / Rim not working when Backfacing Geometry node applied
I have an object (packaging box) which has a different material on each side with a solidify modifier to give the box some thickness. Normally it's easy to add a colour to the rim using material offset/rim options but it doesn't seem to work with the Backfacing geometry node applied to the material (which allows it to be double sided). Is there a way to give the rim a simple white colour?

Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ? And add pictures of what you have and what you are expecting (or as default, what is wrong in the first picture).

Hard to tell without screenshots, but I'm not sure what you are doing with the Backfacing there... if you give the box a Solidify modifier, the backfaces are inside the "thickness", it only makes if your face has no thickness or when you flip faces to turn the inside out

Unfortunately you do not show your Materials tab where we could see how your materials are sorted etc., so here is a general overview how this works, first of all the backface material then the materials for the Solidify modifier.
Let's say I have this material where the frontface or outside is blue, the backface or inside is red:

If you now add a Solidify modifier, it generates thickness, but with the default setting Rim > Fill enabled, this is a closed mesh. All face normals are pointing outward, so you only see blue. Of course there is the Normals > Flip option, but this will flip all faces, not just the ones generated by the modifier and everything would be red. So this way you cannot show a different backface material.

If you disable the rim fill, you can see the red color inside on the backfaces:

What you show in your screenshot though is that you have enabled Only Rim, which would let you see the backface color, however it no longer looks as if the object has thickness to it, it is just like an infinitely thin sheet folded up.

So the correct way to set this up would be to use different materials for different parts of the solidified object. To do that, you can use the Materials settings in the modifier. It seems like you already tried that since the Rim value is 1 instead of the default 0.
Important to know now is that this is an offset, not the material slot index. It says Material Offset, which affects the newly generated faces, but the Rim value is also an offset even though it is not written there.
With this you can have the base material for the original faces, another material for the generated faces and a third material for the rim by setting the Material Offset for example to 1, and the Rim to 2. This way, the generated faces could get a material which you would otherwise have used for the Backfacing:

And here comes the important offset part. If I had some more materials and I gave the object different materials on different faces like this (modifier disabled and I have removed the backface red)

then the result of the Solidify modifier would look like that:

In this case, I have added some more materials to the object. Previously, the original faces were all blue - the material in slot 0. The generated faces were the material in slot 1 and the rim material slot 2.
But now some original faces are blue (0), one is purple (1) and one is white (2). Therefore the generated faces are purple (0 + 1 = 1), white (1 + 1 = 2) and green (2 + 1 = 3). The rim is white (0 + 2 = 2), green (1 + 2 = 3) and yellow (2 + 2 = 4). So the values you set in the modifier are not absolute slot indices, but get added (or subtracted if you enter negative values) to the original indices.
Depending on what you want to this can be helpful to change the rim and generated faces according to whatever color their original faces had. But now comes an issue: what can you do now when you want to have many different materials on the original faces, but always the same for the rim and generated faces.
So for example, if the original faces are blue, green, yellow and red but the generated faces should always be purple and the rim always white. Then the tedious method with offset values 1 and 2 could be to have multiple copies of purple and white to place the materials in this order: blue, purple, white, green, purple, white, yellow, purple, white, red, purple, white.
This is of course not very efficient and becomes very annoying if you often want to change colors. But the good news is: no matter how high the values are which you add or subtract as offset, every negative result will be clamped to the minimum of 0, and every high positive result will be clamped to the maximum slot index existing on the object.
Which means, you could for example set the Material Offset to -99, and the Rim offset to +99. With for example six materials this would mean, the Material Offset -99 will always become slot 0, and the Rim +99 will be 5, because with six material slots the maximum index is 5.
The only thing that is left then is to make sure the material for the generated faces is always in the first slot and the material for the rim is always in the last slot - then it does not matter how many materials you have inbetween to put on the original faces. Unless you have more than 99 materials or so, but this can easily be conquered by changing the offsets to -999 and +999 for example.

